# How to create HTML dynamic select option from JSON hash?

Tags: javascript, php, json, select

I have a simple $test value code:

```
$test = A,bb,100|A,ff,200|A,ee,100|D,ee,3|D,gg,10|R,ii,7
```

I have a select tag in my HTML:

```
<select name="datas" id="datas"></select>
```

I need a simple way to create HTML select box from this JSON, like this:

```
<select>
 <option value="">A</option>
 <option value="100">bb</option>
 <option value="200">ff</option>
 <option value="100">ee</option>
</select>
<select>
 <option value="">D</option>
 <option value="3">ee</option>
 <option value="10">gg</option>
</select>
<select>
 <option value="">R</option>
 <option value="7">ii</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is `$test` supposed to hold all that information as one string? If so, you need quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

You mention JSON, a pre-existing `select` and the "php" tag although I don't see how any of those things are relevant to your question.

Please see the code below to produce a `select` with its content, per your requirements:

```js
// This isn't JSON. It's just a string
let $test = "A,bb,100|A,ff,200|A,ee,100|D,ee,3|D,gg,10|R,ii,7";

// Split the initial string where there are | characters and then loop 
// over the resulting array of strings
$test.split("|").forEach(function(values){
  // Create a new `select` element
  const sel = document.createElement("select");
  
  // Split the part of the string that contains the next level
  // values and loop over them
  values.split(",").forEach(function(value){
    // Create an `option` element 
    const opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.textContent = value;  // Set the value to the individual string
    sel.appendChild(opt); // Append the option to the select
  });
  document.body.appendChild(sel);  // Add the select to the page.
});
```

Comment: hello. Thank you for your help. If the values of the first selection options are the same, I would like to combine them into one. select option -> "A", "D", "R"